# How to get Title property from video file in windows with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, metadata

I'm working with a lot of video files which do not have the correct file name but do have the correct Title name in their properties, I need to be able to get the property value from these files.

[image: Properties - Details]

Comment: MediaInfo is designed for, there is a python module https://pymediainfo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I used to solve the problem thanks to @ChristopheMorio for showing me the tool to do so.

Also if you happen to use MediaInfo module make sure that you have the MediaInfo.dll in the same folder as where you are running the python program from.

```
from pymediainfo import MediaInfo
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def get_title_prop(name):
    media_info = MediaInfo.parse(r"H:\Movies\\" + name)
    for track in media_info.tracks:
        if track.track_type == 'General':
            print(track.title)

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir("Movies") if isfile(join("Movies", f))]

for movies in onlyfiles:
    get_title_prop(movies)
```